# How to automatically remove all duplicates property key in bundle resources in .properties file

Tags: intellij-idea, properties-file

I'm using Intellij Idea 2019.1.3. I have in bundle resources .properties files with a lot of duplicates property key.
Is it possible to automatically remove all duplicates in this kind of file?

[image: duplicates keys]

Comment: There are no duplicates on the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, duplicates i have in another lines, but you see that Intellij underlines some keys which are duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think IntelliJ can do that OOB.

I would sort lines (using this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation/)), which will make duplicate lines be on adjacent lines. Then just remove duplicates by replacing `(^.+$)\n\1` by `$1`

`(^.+$)\n\1` - find duplicate lines separated by the new line character
`$1` - back reference to the line